Get multiple A records using dnsjava
I am trying to use dnsjava to get A records. But it seems I can get only ONE A record. Instead from google apps dig I can see there are much more. Furthermore, the record I get is different.
I tried also other DNS servers, for example 1.1.1.1 or 208.67.222.222 but I still get only one A record. If I try Type.ANY, I still get only one A record with 8.8.8.8, and I get NO records with the other DNS servers.
Am I missing something?
My sample is code is (taken from enter link description here):
        Record queryRecord = Record.newRecord(Name.fromString("google.com."), Type.A, DClass.IN);
        Message queryMessage = Message.newQuery(queryRecord);
        Resolver r = new SimpleResolver("8.8.8.8");
        r.sendAsync(queryMessage)
                .whenComplete(
                        (answer, ex) -> {
                            if (ex == null) {
                                System.out.println(answer);
                                List<Record> records = answer.getSection( 1 );
                                System.out.println("XXXXX");
                                for (Record record : records)
                                {
                                    if ( record instanceof ARecord )
                                    {
                                        System.out.println( "XXX ARecord" + ((ARecord) record).getAddress());
                                    }
                                }
                            } else {
                                ex.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        })
                .toCompletableFuture()
                .get();

